# Read serial port in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, iot

I cannot read the serial port, I tried multiple snippets found in the documentation of `flutter_libserialport`, but no luck.

I am using a esp32 and I send on the serial port some data using this micropython code:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    print('{"firmware_type": "keypad", "value": 2}')
    sleep(1)
```

My dart function is:

```
void readSerialData() async {
    SerialPort port = SerialPort("/dev/cu.wchusbserial55390119721");
    final config = SerialPortConfig();
    config.baudRate = 115200;
    port.config = config;
    SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(port, timeout: 10000);

    int bufferIndex = 0;

    Stream<Uint8List> upcomingData = reader.stream.map((data) {
      return data;
    });

    try {
      port.openReadWrite();

      List<int> buffer = [];
      upcomingData.listen((data) {
        buffer.addAll(data);
        bufferIndex += data.length;

        debugPrint('Raw data: $data');

        if (bufferIndex >= 5) {
          String strBuffer = String.fromCharCodes(buffer);
          debugPrint('Buffer: $strBuffer');
          bufferIndex = 0;
          buffer = [];
        }
      });
    } on SerialPortError catch (err, _) {
      debugPrint('SerialPortError: $err');
      port.close();
    } finally {
    }
  }
```

My output is:

```
flutter: Raw data: [101, 39, 58, 32, 50, 125, 13, 10, 39, 107, 101, 121, 112, 97, 100, 39, 44, 32, 39, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 39, 58, 32, 50, 125, 13, 10, 123, 39, 102, 105, 114, 109, 119, 97, 114, 101, 123, 39, 102, 105, 114, 109, 119, 97, 114, 101, 95, 116, 121, 112, 101, 39, 58, 32, 39, 107, 101, 121, 112, 97, 100, 39, 44, 32, 39, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 39, 58, 32, 50, 125, 13, 10, 123, 39, 102, 105, 114, 109, 119, 97, 114, 101, 95, 116, 121, 112, 101, 39, 58, 32, 39, 107, 101, 121, 112, 97, 100, 39, 44, 32, 39, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 39, 58, 32, 50, 125, 13, 10, 123, 39, 102, 105, 114, 109, 119, 97, 114, 101, 95, 116, 121, 112, 101, 39, 58, 32, 39, 107, 101, 121, 112, 97, 100, 39, 44, 32, 39, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 39, 58, 32, 50, 125, 13, 10, 123, 39, 102, 105, 114, 109, 119, 97, 114, 101, 95, 116, 121, 112, 101, 39, 58, 32, 39, 107, 101, 121, 112, 97, 100, 39, 44, 32, 39, 118, 97, 108, 117, 101, 39, 58, 32, 50, 125, 13, 10, 123, 39, 102, 105, 114, 109, 119, 97, 114, 101, 95, 116, 121, 112, 101, 39, 58, 32, 39, 107, 101, 121, 112, 97, 100, 39, 44, 32]
flutter: Buffer: e': 2}
flutter: 'keypad', 'value': 2}
flutter: {'firmware{'firmware_type': 'keypad', 'value': 2}
flutter: {'firmware_type': 'keypad', 'value': 2}
flutter: {'firmware_type': 'keypad', 'value': 2}
flutter: {'firmware_type': 'keypad',
lutter: {'firmware_type': 'keypad',
flutter: Raw data: [226, 161, 134]
flutter: Raw data: [196, 200, 30, 255]
flutter: Raw data: [167, 134, 158]
flutter: Raw data: [248, 240, 78, 255]
flutter: Raw data: [196, 132, 230]
flutter: Raw data: [238, 140]
flutter: Raw data: [255]
flutter: Raw data: [244, 232, 94, 255]
flutter: Raw data: [196, 132, 204]
flutter: Raw data: [242, 161, 134]
flutter: Raw data: [130, 33, 134]
flutter: Raw data: [249, 245, 66, 255]
flutter: Raw data: [196, 132, 204]
flutter: Raw data: [242, 129, 134]
flutter: Buffer: â¡�ÄÈ�ÿ§��øðNÿÄ�æî�ÿôè^ÿÄ�Ìò¡��!�ùõBÿÄ�Ìò��
flutter: Raw data: [238, 12, 63, 255]
flutter: Raw data: [249, 245, 66, 255]
flutter: Raw data: [74, 225, 249]
...
```

It seems is reading the right data at a certain point but then is not working anymore.
Since it's working at times I guess is not related to baudrate and also I can read it well in arduino serial monitor
My guess is that it's either the buffer size that don't match or the new line char '\n', but I am not sure how to tackle that.

Comment: `reader.stream.transform(ascii.decoder).transform(LineSplitter()).listen((line) => print('line: >$line<'))`

Comment: ooops, i missed its `Stream<Uint8List>` and not `Stream<List<int>>`, in that case you have to add `.cast<List<int>>()` before the first `.transform(...)`

Comment: can you give me the full line? I cannot figure it out
 `Stream<List<int>> upcommingData =  reader.stream.cast<List<int>>().transform(ascii.decoder).transform(LineSplitter()).listen((line) => print('line: >$line<')) as Stream<List<int>>;`

Comment: this is the full line: `reader.stream.cast<List<int>>().transform(ascii.decoder).transform(LineSplitter()).listen((line) => print('line: >$line<'));`

Comment: `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Source contains non-ASCII bytes.`
this python code works just fine:
`ser = serial.Serial(
    port="/dev/cu.wchusbserial55390119721",  
    baudrate=115200,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    timeout=1 
)
if ser.isOpen():
    print(f'Successfully opened port {ser.portstr}')
try:
    while True:
        data = ser.readline()
        if data:
            print(f'Received: {data.decode("utf-8").strip()}')`
so my guess to use utf8.decoder but still no luck

Comment: so use `utf8.decoder` instead of `ascii.decoder`

Comment: It's not working either.
Since it fits my purpose and I don't find any other easy way to do it, I will just use a websocket in python and connect to it from flutter.
Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: with `    Stream<Uint8List> upcommingData = reader.stream.cast<List<int>>().transform(ascii.decoder).transform(LineSplitter()).listen((line) => print('line: >$line<')) as Stream<Uint8List>;` I get the error `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Source contains non-ASCII bytes.`
with `var upcommingData = reader.stream.cast<List<int>>().transform(utf8.decoder).transform(LineSplitter()).listen((line) => print('line: >$line<'));` I get this error `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Missing extension byte (at offset 0)`

Comment: also you cannot use `Stream<Uint8List> upcommingData = ...` just use the code I posted: `reader.stream.cast(.....` and your strings will be available inside `listen` method callback

Comment: and if your utf data is malformed use `Utf8Codec(allowMalformed: true).decoder` not `utf8.decoder`

Comment: still not working....I tried with your suggestions and also switched from micropython to C++ and from esp32 to arduino nano, and it's not working in any combination.
The problem may be my dev machine which is macOS.
I searched any other code snippets on the internet and found nothing.
I was under the impression this would be simple :)
As I mention I use the websockets alternative for the moment since it was simple and allowed me to continue with a working projects from start to end, but I will still research how to do it direcly.

Comment: I logged the line using: `reader.stream.cast<List<int>>().listen((line) => print('line1: >$line<'));` and I get different things `line1: >[4]<`, `line1: >[8]<`, `line1: >[250]<`, ...
even my input should be the same `{"firmware_type": "keypad", "value": 1 }`
Here is my full code: https://gist.github.com/mihailacusteanu/ffcdcbe65e639b9239629742b617d238

Comment: try this: `final sink = File('some_path').openWrite(); reader.stream.cast<List<int>>().pipe(sink);` and try to run it for couple of seconds and then check what was written in the file

Comment: "  �Ptbc�:a4�<" and is only writing when running the file and not when actually serial port is sending data.
and for example this is what python sees as raw data: `b'{"firmware_type": "keypad", "value": 1 }\r\n'`

Comment: yes, it's weird, also because if I just print the raw data data and send something from the esp32 I will get into my dart console log this:
flutter: [60, 137]
flutter: [250]
The first thing is that it logged 2 times even I send just once and the second thing is that this list of ints is far to short.
So maybe the dart code is actually right and the problem is somewhere else(communications between Dart and Libserialport C lib).
But also it's responsive, every time I push my button I see 2 logs with 2 list of 1(max 2) ints in it

Comment: and what you see if you run this for a while? `var buffer = <int>[];
reader.stream.listen((data) {
buffer.addAll(data);
while (buffer.length > 20) {
print(buffer.take(20).map((e) => e.toRadixString(16)).join(','));
buffer = buffer.sublist(20);
}
});`

Comment: it actually sends something more:
`flutter: 22,3a,20,31,20,7d,d,a,7b,22,66,69,72,6d,77,61,72,65,5f,74`
`flutter: 79,70,65,22,3a,20,22,6b,65,79,70,61,64,22,2c,20,22,76,61,6c`

Comment: that's what I initially suspected, but I was under the impression that this would be handled by the library.
how can I control this? because the listening is based on when I start my flutter app, right?

Comment: for ascii.decoder:
`flutter: raw data: 60c203c109dd11632605e68650206e03fd
flutter: rawData: [96, 194, 3, 193, 9, 221, 17, 99, 38, 5, 230, 134, 80, 32, 110, 3, 253]
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Source contains non-ASCII bytes.`

for utf8.decoder:
`flutter: raw data: 2301803ac13401a0948a1d731425c48041ff
flutter: rawData: [35, 1, 128, 58, 193, 52, 1, 160, 148, 138, 29, 115, 20, 37, 196, 128, 65, 255]
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 2)`

Comment: but what I put above is only on connection to the serial port, if I send data afterwards IT WORKS!(with utf8.decoder)
`flutter: raw data: 65223a2033207d0d0a
flutter: rawData: [101, 34, 58, 32, 51, 32, 125, 13, 10]
flutter: line: >{"firmware_type": "keypad", "value": 3 }<`

Comment: sorry I have no idea what you do: first all the bytes are ASCII  in range 32..127 (except 13 and 10 of course for new-line sequence) and then out of nowhere you have the garbage like 193, 160 etc, what do you mean by "send data afterwards"???

Comment: It seems it was just a lucky try where I listed to the serial port when "it should", because I re-run the same code afterwards and it's not working anymore
by "send data afterwards" I mean that I push a physical button after my flutter code connects to the serial port, which prints something to the serial port.

Comment: can you give me again the code you had in your github gist?

Comment: using this code: [http://pastebin.com/3Gqk2ZB1](http://pastebin.com/3Gqk2ZB1) it's working IF I make the string sent from esp32 SHORT. With "received: {"value":  2804}" works just fine!

Comment: with a longer string `[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (length): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..4611686018427387903: -37`

Comment: it seems that with a lower baud rate(9600) is actually working!
I receive the string intro multiple messages, but this is fine.
I haven't considered lowered the baud rate since in micropython this is not that easy(without re-burning the firmware every time)

Comment: I am still however curious why would that happen. do you have any idea @pskink ?

Comment: As @jdekarske mention on github there is a bug: github.com/jpnurmi/libserialport.dart/issues/24 and the fix is to copy the config and modified the copied config 
So instead of 
`serialPort.config.baudRate = 115200;`
You just put
`SerialPortConfig config = serialPort.config;` 
`config.baudRate = 115200;` 
`serialPort.config = config;`

Comment: `String.fromCharCodes(data)` works fine

Comment: Full code: `SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(serialPort);
    serialPort.openReadWrite();
    SerialPortConfig config = serialPort.config;
    config.baudRate = 115200;
    serialPort.config = config;


    StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();
    reader.stream.listen((data) {
      var str = String.fromCharCodes(data);
      buffer.write(str);
      if (str.endsWith('\n')) {
        String message = buffer.toString();
        buffer.clear();
        processMessage(message);
      }
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a previous comment the problem wasn't that my esp32 wasn't sending anything.
I could read the output of serial port in other ways than using flutter.
The problem was about a possible bug detailed here: https://github.com/jpnurmi/libserialport.dart/issues/24
And the workaround is to first copy the existing config from the serial port, then change it, then assign the copy back to the serial port:

```
SerialPortReader reader = SerialPortReader(serialPort);   
serialPort.openReadWrite();   
SerialPortConfig config = serialPort.config; 
config.baudRate = 115200;   
serialPort.config = config;
```

Also another workaround, which wasn't an option for me, is to use a lower baudrate(9600).

Answer (score 0):

To make sure your serial data is actually intact, use a terminal like Putty or Tera-Term to open the comport and view the data.
If the data is also corrupted in the terminal, you are probably having a bad connection with the esp32, so make sure to check that. If you have a copy of the esp32, there might be a cheap USB<->UART converter on it which might be the culprit.

If the terminal does work OK, make sure to set up the serial port fully in your dart code; as from the documentation: [SerialPortConfig class](https://pub.dev/documentation/libserialport/latest/libserialport/SerialPortConfig-class.html)

> You should always configure all settings before using a port. There are no default settings applied by the library. When you open a port, it may have default settings from the OS or driver, or the settings left over by the last program to use it.
> [...]
> You should always set baud rate, data bits, parity and stop bits.

So make sure to do this.